# Display years part in spinner mode of Android Studio DatePicker

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker, android-datepicker

I am not sure how configure Android Studio DatePicker so it is able to hide calendar part and display in a spinner mode years also.

Is it possible to do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DatePicker instance and call [setCalendarViewShown(boolean shown)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setCalendarViewShown(boolean))

```
<DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```